# Multi select from react-select with redux-form not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-select

So iam using multi select from react-select with redux-form with the onBlur hack(?) which is working fine behind the curtain because when i submit it I have the selected data in values

BUT after visiting any multi select field (even if i dont select anything) I end up with no values at all (nothing is displayed but this
[image]
))

```
const options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

<Select
            value="one"
            options={options}
            multi={true}
            {...input}
            onBlur={() => {
              input.onBlur({...input.value})
            }
          }
        />
```

So i end up with values in the redux state but I cant see any values in the field. Anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used more modern versions of `react-select`, but a year ago, there were some issues with having to `split()` the string value by the `delimiter` to get the values as an array, and then `join()` them again to give to the component.

Stuff like this:

```
if (multi) {
  selectValue = value ? value.join(delimiter) : ''
} else {
  selectValue = value || null
}
```

I recommend examining exactly what the value is in Redux, using Redux DevTools, and what value prop is getting passed to `react-select`. I'm sure you'll find the problem in there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erik. I did exactly that after posting this question and it turned out I had to pass in array of selected values in the onBlur func instead of object so doing `input.onBlur([...input.value])` solved the problem. Having said that do you recommend using something else other than react-select? Also using redux-form makes it hard for me to control the state of the form inputs. Do you recommend it for someone new to redux?

Comment: PS i know redux-form is your repo so i hope you aren't biased (hehe)

Comment: Heh. There is another lib, called `react-redux-form`, that might fit better with your way of thinking.

And no, I don't really have a better alternative to react-select for multi selections.

Answer (score 11):

Here's example how to make it works. react-select (1.0.0-rc.2), redux-form (5.3.4)

**SelectInput.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

export default (props) => (
  <Select
    {...props}
    value={props.input.value}
    onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
  />
);
```

**MyAwesomeComponent.js**

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import SelectInput from './SelectInput.js';

class MyAwesomeComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const options = [
      {'label': 'Germany', 'value': 'DE'},
      {'label': 'Russian Federation', 'value': 'RU'},
      {'label': 'United States', 'value': 'US'}
    ];
  return (
    <Field
      name='countries'
      options={options}
      component={SelectInput}
      multi
    />
  )
};
```

Comment: This works well with both multi and non-multi selects.

Comment: Best answer! Save me a day!