# Can a redux-form accept multiple values from a react-select component?

Tags: redux-form, react-select

I'm hoping to display multiple values from a react-select component in my redux-form and then pass those values to a function that will update state. Is this possible? Can a redux-form take multiple inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, can you check my answer, please? If you have any questions - feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You have to create a custom component, that will wrap `react-select` and will use the props, passed down by `redux-form` `<Field component={YourCustomComponent} />`.

1. [Here's](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/field.md/#usage) is described how to create such a custom component in the official `redux-form` documentation.
2. Here, you will find such already implemented components, these wrap `react-select` and connects them with `redux-form`: [ReactJS: How to wrap react-select in redux-form field ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650273/reactjs-how-to-wrap-react-select-in-redux-form-field)
3. In order to handle **multi** values, please refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762700/4312466).

Basically, the code example from resource 3. (credits to the author) should be enough for integrating `react-select` + `redux-form` + handling `multi` values:

**SelectInput.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

export default (props) => (
  <Select
    {...props}
    value={props.input.value}
    onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
  />
);
```

**MyAwesomeComponent.js**

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import SelectInput from './SelectInput.js';

class MyAwesomeComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const options = [
      {'label': 'Germany', 'value': 'DE'},
      {'label': 'Russian Federation', 'value': 'RU'},
      {'label': 'United States', 'value': 'US'}
    ];
  return (
    <Field
      name='countries'
      options={options}
      component={SelectInput}
      multi
    />
  )
};
```